# Sending Headers with a GET request to Third Party API

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to build a small full-stack application, where my frontend code will only interact with my backend, and the backend will call Third Party API to fetch results and then do whatever it wants with it.The third party API I am using requires an `Accept` , `app_id` and `app_key` headers for any request.

I can send a `GET` request directly to my third party API with Postman and fetch results just fine, but when I try to send `GET` request through my NodeJS API, I am receiving `status 403` instead . I am using `node-fetch` for this purpose.

The API I am using is [Oxford Dictionary API](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com)

Here is the code for my `index.js` file

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const router = require('./routes/router');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || '5000';
const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server is up and running at http://${host}:${port} `));
```

Here is the code for my `router.js` file.

```
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const router = express.Router();
const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL;
const fields = 'definitions';

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        status: "successfully connected !"
    });
});

router.post('/create', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.word);
    const url = `${BASE_URL}entries/en-gb/${req.body.word}?fields=${fields}&strictMatch=true`;
    const newHeaders = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "app_id": process.env.APP_ID,
        "app_key": process.env.API_KEY
    }

    fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: { newHeaders } })
        .then((results) => {
            console.log(results);
        }).then(results => {
            res.json(results);
        }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Following is the `results` i am receiving :-

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object]
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-gb/swim?fields=definitions&strictMatch=true',
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Rest Assured, the `environment variables` are all set with accurate values.

I want to be ale to attach `headers` and send a `GET` request to third party API and successfully fetch results. Also, I want to be able to send those `results` back to my client.

I have few questions regarding my code.

1. Is it correct to use `fetch` inside of an express route ?
2. If yes, why is this returning `status 403` ?
3. If no, what is the correct way to achieve this ?
4. What does this `headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },` mean ?

**I am a newbie in web development, so this question might seem stupid to some veterans here but please help me out. I have read the following resources but none of them helped me:-**

[Accessing [Symbol(Response internals)] from JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393861/accessing-symbolresponse-internals-from-json-response)

[Node-Fetch API GET with Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099282/node-fetch-api-get-with-headers)

[How to fetch from third party API inside backend route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379230/how-to-fetch-from-third-party-api-inside-backend-route)

**Edit:**

I used `app-id` and `app-key` instead of `app_id` and `app_key` which I have corrected now but the problem isn't yet solved.

Comment: Check https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation/making-requests-to-the-api, and you’ll see the header names are supposed to be `app_id` and `app_key`. You used `app-id` and `app-key` instead.

Comment: Hi. thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the mistake but still the response is same.

Comment: You say `headers: { newHeaders }` , but `newHeaders` is already an object. Try `headers: newHeaders `. In any event, inspect the outgoing request.

Comment: @LeeGoddard thanks. That solved my problem. After further tweaking the code, i am now able to fetch data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you had a typo:

`headers: { newHeaders }` -- `newHeaders` is already an object, so use `headers: newHeaders`.